# Excel rows are not getting converted to UTF-8 files

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code to convert the text

```
・OTD in house ,95% member: Each、Leader :ALL（メンバーは個々の実績、リーダーはチーム全体の実績）
・Service Return, vs CY20: improve 10%　member: Each、Leader :ALL（メンバーは個々の実績、リーダーはチーム全体の実績）
・ Revenue (Leader only) (各チームごとの売り上げ、リーダーのみ)
    TEK/KEI: 545,068Kyen
  　FLK:NET 459,582K yen
・Productivity ( units/ total time): improve 10%、 member: Each、Leader :ALL（生産性　昨年実績から10%改善、メンバーは個々の実績、リーダーはチーム全体の実績）
・Shipment Overdue Rate vs CY20: improve 10%  member:ALL、Leader :ALL
（売り上げ済みの案件で入荷から出荷まで稼働日が下記のターゲットに対して過ぎている超過の件の10%削減、全員がチーム全体の実績）
```

in UTF-8 text file format. But it is converting to UTF-16 LE

```
Sub SaveWorksheet()

Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
Dim MyDataWorksheet As Worksheet

Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set MyDataWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim OutputFile As StringDim CellValue As StringDim CurrentRow As LongDim CurrentCol As LongDim CurrentCharacter As LongDim LastRow As LongDim MyString As StringDim fso, f

LastRow = MyDataWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

For CurrentRow = 2 To LastRow

    OutputFile = "C:\Users\PARSAH\Music\ClobFiles-" & CurrentRow & ".txt"Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(OutputFile, 8, True, -1)


    f.WriteLine MyDataWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value
    f.Close
    
Next CurrentRow

MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Stream object from the ADODB library to save each file as a UTF-8 encoded file.

Also, since you're referring to the active workbook, you can replace . . .

```
Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
```

with

```
Set MyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
```

Also, you should qualify your Rows reference, otherwise you could get an error if the active sheet is not a worksheet.  So you should replace . . .

```
LastRow = MyDataWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
```

with

```
With MyDataWorksheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Accordingly, your macro can be amended as follows . . .

```
Sub SaveWorksheet()

    Const adTypeText As Long = 2
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite As Long = 2

    Dim oStream As Object
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    
    Dim MyWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim MyDataWorksheet As Worksheet
    
    Set MyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set MyDataWorksheet = MyWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With MyDataWorksheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    Dim OutputFile As String
    Dim CurrentRow As Long
    
    With oStream
    
        .Charset = "UTF-8"
        .Type = adTypeText
    
        For CurrentRow = 2 To LastRow
        
            OutputFile = "C:\Users\PARSAH\Music\ClobFiles-" & CurrentRow & ".txt"
        
            .Open
            .WriteText MyDataWorksheet.Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value
            .SaveToFile OutputFile, adSaveCreateOverWrite
            .Close
            
        Next CurrentRow
        
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```